# Rollback drawRect:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-2d

Is there any way to quit from `drawRect:` without refresh the current `UIView`?
For example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 30.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 30.0);
CGContextStrokePath(context);


//I would like to return from here and rollback all changes in drawRect:

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't. If you explain why you want to do this, perhaps someone can offer an alternative solution.

Comment: It's a map application. When the user moves the map, a new thread(let's call this thread1) starts redraw the screen. Then the user moves the map again and now thread2(the newest thread) has to redraw the map. But if thread1 did not finish the drawing, the screen will 'flesh' the thread1's image for a quick moment. So it's better to rollback the thread1's drawRect: method and draw just thread2's image.

Comment: This sounds odd. You can't redraw the screen more than 50fps. The time spent in drawrect should be less than 1/50th second for gui to be responsive. If your drawing is taking longer this it sounds like you need to draw to a texture in a background thread and when that is ready blit it to the screen in drawrect (which will take much less than 1/50th sec). Your Question then becomes how to cancel the background thread and start a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't started drawing into the context, it might be possible to just return from `drawRect:`. You'd have to set the `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` property of the view to NO before.

After starting to draw in the context, the view/layer will always update its content.